# Layered navigation is missing on search results after Magento upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, upgrade, magento-1.14

Having just completed an upgrade from CE v1.9 to EE 1.14, I find that the layered navigation (left block) is missing from the search results page.

The problem is that several modules and layout XML files seem to reference this block (catalog/layer/view.phtml) and I'm not sure which module removed this block.

Is there a way I can determine the layout files which were used to render the page, and the order in which they were parsed? I tried Commercebug but it doesn't actually say which XML files are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Magneto_Debug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug.html).

With this, you can see all layout updates used in the page and what are the layout XML files used for each layout update.

See the image below:

[image: Magneto_Debug Layout Tab]